# Why is it that Next.js and Gatsby.js require that Node.js be installed, but React.js, by itself, doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, gatsby, create-react-app

...considering the fact that Next.js and Gatsby.js are all built on React.js?

Is it that the development environments, themselves, are Node applications? Or is there something I'm missing here?

I've been using React for a bit over a year now, but I'm still relatively new to Next.js and Gatsby.js and I haven't seen this answered in one place. So I've been curious about this.

This question could also apply to [Facebook's Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started).

I appreciate your help.

#### From the Docs:

- [*Node.js 10.13 or later* is a system requirement for Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs)
- [*Gatsby... requires the Node.js runtime*](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/node/)
- [*You’ll need to have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6* to use Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

Comment: Next.js and gatsby are not exclusively front-end tools

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Where does that leave Create React App, then? That's surely used exclusively for the frontend, right?

Comment: create-react-app uses node too. not a runtime, but to generate the output code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Next & Gatsby are ultimately running on a server somewhere, and probably your local machine during development, in order to serve rendered HTML on the initial page load. Node, [which is essentially Chrome's JS engine](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-v8-javascript-engine), is the most popular way to run JS *outside* of a browser. React can run entirely in the browser, maybe even using that same engine. In order to run `create-react-app`, you're going to need to run some JS, and since you're outside of the browser, you're going to need a runtime, like Node. If you don't want to install it, you can manually do everything `create-react-app` does, and develop locally, without Node, running your code in the browser.

Comment: So Next & Gatsby run on a server (outside of a browser) *and* are running JS code, so they both need the Node runtime?

Comment: Correct, that's my understanding, even if the "server" in this case is your dev machine.